# Beautiful Soup return None

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been looking around and even found some responses to things similar to this but none of the solutions worked.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError


url = u'https://www.zapimoveis.com.br/venda/imoveis/pe+recife/?transacao=Venda&tipo=Imóvel%20usado&onde=,Pernambuco,Recife,,,,,,BR%3EPernambuco%3ENULL%3ERecife,-8.057838,-34.882897'.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36'}

try:
    req = Request(url, headers = headers)
    html = urlopen(req)
    print(html.read())
except HTTPError as e:
    print(e.status, e.reason)

except URLError as e:
    print(e.reason)
```

When I try to create a BeautifulSoup Object it doesn't work.

```
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(),'html.parser')
```

Comment: You don't have a variable called `html` but you do have one called `html5`.  What do you mean, specifically, by "doesn't work".  What is the output you're expecting?

Comment: Hi, prieber! I was trying a lot of solutions in the code so I rename some part of the variables in the code. But that's wasn't the problem. But ill edit the question. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to `.encode()`/`.decode()` the URL. Simply use the url in `requests.get` and create a soup:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.zapimoveis.com.br/venda/imoveis/pe+recife/?transacao=Venda&tipo=Imóvel%20usado&onde=,Pernambuco,Recife,,,,,,BR%3EPernambuco%3ENULL%3ERecife,-8.057838,-34.882897"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

for listing in soup.select(".card-container"):
    print(listing.select_one(".simple-card__text").text)
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
A Pernambuco Construtora apresenta o Arcos da Aurora Prince, lançamento na Rua da Aurora, com uma vista espetacular para o Rio Capibaribe e o charme de viver em um dos lugares mais...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pronto Para Morar - 2 e 3 Quartos. No charmoso Cais da Aurora.Condições super especiais para você adquirir agora o seu apartamento. Lazer completo.Localizado no Centro...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Praticidade e Segurança, com a melhor Localização.PRÓXIMO AO QUARTEL DO EXÉRCITODiferenciais:Antena ColetivaCentral de Gás Estacionamento para visitante...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VENHA CONHECER SEU NOVO ENDEREÇO NA AV. BOA VIAGEMAMPLO APARTAMENTO, COM 112 m², DISTRIBUÍDO EM AMPLA SALA, VARANDA INTEGRADA, 3 QUARTOS, (1 SUÍTE), DEPENDÊNCIA, COM PORCEL...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
O apartamento está localizado no bairro Espinheiro possui 137 metros quadrados com 3 quartos sendo 3 suites e 1 banheiroPossui espaço jardinado, playground, salão de festas, ac...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Casa com 210 m² de área construída por trás da Caixa Econômica da Avenida Agamenom Magalhães. Terreno 360 m². 8 salas. 04 WC.Ótima localização.Ligar : -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Apartamento no 26 andar, com vista privilegiada, super ventilado, 3 quartos sendo 1suíte, WC Social, Sala para 2 ambientes, Cozinha, área de serviço, WC Serviço, dependência revert...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Vendo Cobertura de cinema, excelente localização na praia de Boa Viagem, pertinho do Mar!!! APARTAMENTO4 Quartos sendo 2 suítes3 banheiro social2 vagas na garag...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Apartamento a venda no Bairro da Boa Vista, 52m², 2 quartos, varanda, 1 vaga de garagem, novo pronto para morar.LAZER E DIVERSÃO PARA TODAS AS IDADES:- Piscina Adulto / Inf...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
O Jardins da Ilha é um empreendimento com a marca Moura Dubeux em uma localização mais que especial, em um dos bairros mais procurados do Recife e com uma localização que lhe deixa...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Casa, tipo Duplex Nascente- toda reformada ótimo padrão Ideal como residência e para negócios: clínicas, atelier e cursos executivos.... 4 quartos / 1 Quarto suíte / Dependência de...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Apartamento na Encruzilhada com 03 quartos com opção de 02 vagas de garagem!Não perca a oportunidade de comprar seu apartamento com uma ótima negociação.Hall de ent...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Reserva Polidoro, seu Moura Dubeux no melhor da Várzea.EM BREVE, PRONTO PARA MORAR (Obras em 90%)Preste á ser entregue, o Reserva Polidoro é simplesmente o melhor custo ben...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Apartamento a venda em Recife com 2 quartos no Aurora Trend, excelente oportunidade, INFO: 9 9 8 8 0 - 4 7 1 6 - Marcos Santos, o Aurora Trend é um empreendimento perfeito pra você...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Excelente apartamento em andar alto no bairro do Espinheiro, Edf. Saint James. São 57m² distribuídos em 2 quartos sendo 1 suíte, 1 wc social, sala ampla para dois ambientes, cozinh...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Situado em uma das transversais da Av. Boa Viagem no bairro do Pina, um dos endereços mais desejados de Recife, a poucos passos do mar e com toda estrutura de lazer e segurança da...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Para facilitar o contato, fale diretamente pelo WhatsApp: Yago Reys.Oportunidade no Edf. Felicitá Prince em Boa ViagemApartamento de 01 Quarto- Área útil de 42m...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
O apartamento de 81 metros quadrados está localizado no bairro Boa Viagem com 3 quartos sendo 1 suíte e 02 vagas de estacionamento. Fica a alguns minutos do shopping center Riomar...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Excelente apartamento no Edifício Rio Verde, com localização privilegiada na Avenida João de Barros, bairro da Boa Vista, próximo à Universidade de Pernambuco-UPE e à Universidade...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EDIFICIO PRAÇA DO ROSARINHO PRINCE – UM DOS MELHORES PREDIOS DA ZONA NORTE, LOCALIZAÇÃO ESPETACULAR. Em frente à Praça do Rosarinho 33 pavimentos tipo, 04 apartamentos por anda...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Apartamento com 57m2, 2 Quartos, 1Suíte - lazer completoquartos sendo 1 suite e 2 banheirosPossui academia, jardim, playground, salão de festas, petplay, piscina adulto com...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ótimo apartamento na Tamarineira com 77M², 3 quartos, sendo 1 suíte, com móveis fixos e 1 vaga coberta na garagem.Condomínio com total estrutura de segurança e lazer, composta...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
O Edifício:18 pavimentos, sendo 1 pavimento térreo, 1 pavimento vazado/1º pavimento tipo com 3 apartamentos e acima deste mais 15 pavimentos tipo elevado com 3 apartamentos por...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DIFERENCIAIS CONSTRUTORA CONIC - APTO 107 M2 4 QTOS, SENDO 3 SUÍTES, SALA 2 AMBIENTES, VARANDA COZINHA, WC SOCIAL, ÁERA DE SERVIÇO COMPLETA, 03 VAGAS.APARTAMENTO 4...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hi, Andrej!!! Thank you very much! It solved my problem! I was using because I was trying to use the urlopen from the urllib library and the url had some encoding problems... I still don't get the difference between the Requests, request and request.get...in this case you didn't use the urlopen...